# Flutter Switch animation Bug

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, switch-statement

[image]

When I click this switch, it only switches to the middle. How I can fix this issue?

Here is the Code:

```dart
Switch.adaptive(
  value: state,
  activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  activeTrackColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
  inactiveThumbColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  onChanged: (bool s) {
    setState(() {
      state = s;
      print(state);
      if (state == false) {
        preis2 = widget.preisKlein.toString();
        kleinGross = 'klein';
      } else {
        preis2 = widget.preisGross.toString();
        kleinGross = 'groß';
      }
    });
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue in beta release. I've tried running the following snippet on both stable and beta channel

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 120,
      child: Switch(
        value: state,
        onChanged: (bool s) {
          setState(() {
            state = s;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

On beta channel I got the same result as you, whereas on stable it worked like expected.

I've raised the following ticket: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78733

As for the solution, simply switch to stable channel until the issue is resolved or don't change switch width for the time being.